# React Native Snap Carousel Functional Component Issue

Tags: react-native, react-native-snap-carousel

I'm using this snack as a template for implementing my own carousel component. This template is using Class Component and I converted it to a Functional component

https://snack.expo.io/@bd-arc/react-native-snap-carousel-%7C-example-with-custom-interpolations

I added this to my project and I believe some error is happening when rendering the Carousel but I'm unable to tell. It renders - but not all the components are rendering. I have only changed the Carousel itself to a function component. The problem is the  is not showing below the Carousel - also if I add multiple VideoCarousel's, only the first one displays.

My code is below

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

import Header from './components/header';
import VideoCarousel from './components/videoCarousel';

import tailwind from 'tailwind-rn';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={tailwind('flex pt-12 items-center bg-gray-300 h-full')}>
      <Header />
      <VideoCarousel />
      <VideoCarousel />
    </View>
  )
};

export default App;
```

VideoCarousel.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Dimensions, StyleSheet, Alert } from 'react-native';

import Carousel from 'react-native-snap-carousel'; // Version can be specified in package.json

import { scrollInterpolator, animatedStyles } from './../utils/animations';

const SLIDER_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const ITEM_WIDTH = Math.round(SLIDER_WIDTH * 0.7);
const ITEM_HEIGHT = Math.round(ITEM_WIDTH * 3 / 4);

const DATA = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  DATA.push(i)
}

const VideoCarousel = () => {

  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  _renderItem = (index) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.itemLabel}>{`Item ${index.index}`}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Carousel
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
        sliderWidth={SLIDER_WIDTH}
        itemWidth={ITEM_WIDTH}
        containerCustomStyle={styles.carouselContainer}
        inactiveSlideShift={0}
        onSnapToItem={(index) => setIndex(index)}
        scrollInterpolator={scrollInterpolator}
        slideInterpolatedStyle={animatedStyles}
        useScrollView={true}          
      />
      <Text style={styles.counter}>
        Test
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  carouselContainer: {
    marginTop: 50
  },
  itemContainer: {
    width: ITEM_WIDTH,
    height: ITEM_HEIGHT,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'dodgerblue'
  },
  itemLabel: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 24
  },
  counter: {
    marginTop: 400,
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: "black",
  }
});

export default VideoCarousel;
```

Comment: Can you share the solution if you managed to get it to work ? thanks